# Cisco ThreatGrid Submit Sample API... How do I send a Sample File?

Tags: java, rest, cisco

I am not able to successfully call the ThreatGrid Submit Sample API using Java.  I've used Java to call APIs in the past, so I have experience setting up these calls.

I should be POSTing to https://panacea.threatgrid.com/api/v2/samples and provide parameters in the body of my request.

I also need to write the sample file (the file being evaluated) into the body of the request.

I understand that I'll need to set the 'Content-Type' to 'multipart/form-data;' and provide a Boundary string to separate the parts of the request.

Upon calling the submit API, I am receiving an HTTP 400 Bad Request with the following error return:

```
{"api_version":2,"id":7162013,"error":{"message":"The parameter sample is required. ","code":400,"errors":[{"code":400,"message":"The parameter sample is required. ","help":"/doc/main/index.html","report":"support@threatgrid.com"}]}}
```

This is saying that I am not providing the 'sample' parameter.  Sample is the file being submitted for threat evaluation.  Note that my second part (section of data) that I am sending in the request body was given the name 'sample'.

Here's how I am setting the request headers in my connection:

```
    connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=BOUNDARY");
    connection.addRequestProperty("cache-control", "no-cache");
    connection.addRequestProperty("accept", "*/*");
    connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Length", "164784" );
    connection.addRequestProperty("Host", "panacea.threatgrid.com");
```

Here's an example of what I believe I am writing to the connection's output stream:

```
--BOUNDARY

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="application/json"
{"private":"true","vm":"win7-x64","email_notification":false}

--BOUNDARY

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sample"; filename="GracePeriod.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

[Bytes of the Sample File being submitted to ThreatGrid api]

--BOUNDARY--
```

Code that builds the body of my request:

```
        String boundaryString = "BOUNDARY";
        String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
        File sampleFileToUpload = new File(fileUrl);

        outputStream.writeBytes(LINE_FEED);
        outputStream.writeBytes(LINE_FEED);
        outputStream.writeBytes("--" + boundaryString); 
        outputStream.writeBytes(LINE_FEED);
        outputStream.writeBytes(LINE_FEED);

        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"application/json\""); 
        outputStream.writeBytes(LINE_FEED);

        //  Build the parameters that get placed into the Header
        Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        headers.put("private", "true");
        headers.put("vm", "win7-x64");
        headers.put("email_notification", false);   
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String body = gson.toJson(headers);

        outputStream.writeBytes( body );
        outputStream.writeBytes(LINE_FEED);
        outputStream.writeBytes(LINE_FEED);

        outputStream.writeBytes("--" + boundaryString);
        outputStream.writeBytes(LINE_FEED);
        outputStream.writeBytes(LINE_FEED);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name='sample'; filename='"+sampleFileToUpload.getName()+"'");
        outputStream.writeBytes(LINE_FEED);        
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: application/pdf");
        outputStream.writeBytes(LINE_FEED);
        outputStream.writeBytes(LINE_FEED);


        //  Write the contents of the file being submitted...
        FileInputStream inputStream  = new FileInputStream(sampleFileToUpload);
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();     
        int nRead;
        byte[] dataArray = new byte[16384];         
        while ((nRead = inputStream.read(dataArray, 0, dataArray.length)) != -1) {
            buffer.write(dataArray, 0, nRead);
        }       
        buffer.flush();
        byte[] bytes  = buffer.toByteArray();           
        inputStream.close();

        outputStream.write(bytes);

        outputStream.writeBytes(LINE_FEED);
        outputStream.writeBytes(LINE_FEED);

        outputStream.writeBytes("--" + boundaryString + "--");
        outputStream.writeBytes(LINE_FEED);
        outputStream.writeBytes(LINE_FEED);

        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
```

I should be getting the HTTP 200 message and the response message that contains details about my submission.

Hopefully, someone has done this before and can show me the error in my ways.

Thank you!

EDIT:  I forgot to mention that I can use the Postman app to set up and call this API successfully.  I set the 'private', 'vm', 'email_notification' and 'sample' items in the body of the request as form-data.  Postman allows you to set these items as either text or file (there is a dropdown).  In the case of 'sample', I set  it to file and Postman allows me to 'attach' the file.  I used the Postman console to look at what is being sent in the request and I tried to emulate that in my Java code as best as possible.  There must be other detail that I need that Postman doesn't show me in the console.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the documentation, but typically the word `parameter` means query parameter. I hope that helps in some way.

Comment: Sam - The API documentation is here: https://panacea.threatgrid.com/mask/api-doc/api/v2/samples, but you'll need a login to view it (I believe).  The documentation states that the sample param is of type File and it is specified on the form (not query).

Comment: I think the first thing you need to do is log the request you are sending. It will be hard to do anything else.

Comment: Aside: trusting the filename to be safe to insert into the header without any escaping? If you're dealing with potentially-malicious content (and if you weren't, why use the product?), that might not be wise. Keep in mind that UNIX filenames are perfectly capable of containing quotes, newlines, &c.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion... Yes, these things need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able (head slightly bloodied) to get the API to respond successfully (HTTP 200 Message).  I'll provide the details that got it to work if this can help anyone in the future.

Upon looking at the definition of the API, it states that "The request parameters are to encoded as 'multipart/form-data'".  I was sending some of the parameters as JSON data.  I decided that I needed to send each parameter as a separate form variable, each separated by a Boundary marker (I tried this once earlier, but I came back to that same idea).

After doing that I started paying attention to the detail of the spaces (CRLFs) after each item in the Request body.  The API is very sensitive to how the data is formatted in the body.  I found that it requires a CRLF before the actual value of the form data that you are sending.

Here's an example of the request body as I am sending it:

```
--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="private"
[CRLF (a space)]
true
--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="vm"
[CRLF (a space)]
win7-x64
--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email_notification"
[CRLF (a space)]
false
--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sample"; 
filename="CourseCompletionCertificate.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
[CRLF (a space)]
[data stream of the Sample file in a byte array...]
--BOUNDARY--
```

I found examples of multipart/form-data and I noticed the use of CRLFs in the data and I did my best to copy how that data was being sent.  It was after that detail that the API responded with success.